# Commerce Cloud Documentation

Tags: commerce-cloud

**Background**

The Salesforce Documentation is mostly publicly accessible.

**Question**

- Is the Salesforce Commerce Cloud Documentation for developers publicly
  accessible?
- And where can I find the documentation?

Comment: hope the answer in this thread gives you some direction - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38769148/i-want-to-start-learning-demandware

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Dustin Tran is correct that some of it is currently private. Commerce Cloud documentation is available in the [Commerce Cloud XChange](https://xchange.demandware.com/) site and what is often called: [Infocenter](https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp). The prior is somewhat analogous to Salesforce SE whereas the latter is more traditional API documentation and product manuals. Infocenter is publicly available as of January 2019.

In order to access XChange, you must have an [Account Manager](https://account.demandware.com/) credential that is granted by a partner or customer organization that has a standing contract with Commerce Cloud.

Additionally, the support team has developed some [Knowledge Base Articles](https://support-demandware.force.com/customer/login?ec=302&inst=a&startURL=%2Fcustomer%2Fhome%2Fhome.jsp) that are accessible if a customer or partner organization has created a Support account for you. These articles are supplementary to the Infocenter documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Commerce Cloud documentation is available to the public now:
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/index.jsp

Comment: I don't think this is a "link-only answer" inasmuch as the question is meant to be answered via a link or reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer this site for full documentation

https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.demandware.dochelp%2Fjsdoc%2Fdist%2Fjs%2Fserver%2Ftutorial-CreateController.html

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce SE! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Quick reply that Salesforce Commerce Cloud (formerly Demandware) is still in private space. Hopefully, it will be opened follow up Salesforce practice.

Comment: No, the documentation is not a private space anymore. I heard that it is hosted on a sandbox and the documentation is a storefront of that sandbox, that is easily available to all.

Comment: @Code_Ninja while it is publicly available, it’s not “hosted” on a sandbox or storefront. But you _can_ download _some_ of the documentation from a sandbox. (Only the B2C Commerce API docs) UX Studio does this any time you connect it to an instance. So it’s probably already on your hard drive within the server connection directory.